# Trying to find number of regex matches in C++, returning zero

Tags: c++

I have implemented the following code to try and count the number of matches in the given string; in this case it should be 1.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>

unsigned countMatches(std::string text, std::regex expr);
    
int main()
{
    std::string phrase = "Hello world";

    std::regex pattern = std::regex("world");

    std::cout << countMatches(phrase, pattern) << std::endl;
    
    return 0;
}

unsigned countMatches(std::string text, std::regex expr)
{
    std::smatch matches;
    
    while(std::regex_search(text, matches, expr))
    text = matches.suffix().str();
   
    return matches.size();
}
```

However it always prints 0 and I can't see why.

Comment: The loop will end when there's no matches.

Comment: I think you wanted to accumulate something, but forgot to accumulate

Comment: a good case for [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging). Explain to someone what your code does and why, line by line, in all details. Explain it to your coffee pot in case you have no rubber duck. If it doesn't help you can still use a debugger

Comment: You are right that removing the loop will give you a 1 but then, if I change the the regex to just "o" I still get a 1 when I should get a 2 so it seems that the loop is necessary but I may not be implementing it right

Comment: Side note: While you do modify `text` you don't `expr` in the function, so why accept it by value (i.e. needlessly creating a copy)? You should accept it by const reference instead (`std::string text, std::regex const& expr`).

Comment: `size_t count = 0; while(...) { count += matches.size(); text = suffix; } return count;` might be what you actually are after... (or simply `++count;` as `matches.size()` should be 1 anyway).

Answer (score 1):

> However it always prints 0 and I can't see why.

You call `regex_search` in a while loop. The body of the loop (eventhough wrongly indented) is updating `text`. The first iteration does find 1 match. But then you update text to be an empty string (the suffix of the match) and in the next iteration there are 0 matches. This is the value your function returns.

Instead you should **accumulate** the number of matches:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>

size_t countMatches(std::string text, std::regex const & expr)
{
    std::smatch matches;
    size_t result{ 0 };

    while (std::regex_search(text, matches, expr))
    {
        result += matches.size();  // <--- accumulate number of matches
        text = matches.suffix().str();
    }

    return result;
}

int main()
{
    std::string phrase = "Hello world";
    std::cout << countMatches(phrase, std::regex("world")) << std::endl;
    std::cout << countMatches(phrase, std::regex("o")) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
1
2
```

**Note** that I changed the return value to `size_t` as this is the type of `matches.size()`. I also added `const &` to the `expr` parameter to avoid a copy.

Comment: I don't think this works either. Yes I now get a 1 when searching for my original expression but if I shorten "world" to "o" there should now be 2 matches but the program still prints 1.

Comment: Please check my updated solution. It will print 2 for "o" (and 1 for "world") as expected.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to iterate over the input string, and count a number of matches, you can use `std::sregex_iterator`.

[[Demo]](https://godbolt.org/z/saxj8z8eK)

```cpp
unsigned countMatches(const std::string& text, std::regex expr) {
    unsigned ret{};
    for (auto it = std::sregex_iterator(text.begin(), text.end(), expr);
        it != std::sregex_iterator{};
        ++it, ++ret);
    return ret;
}

// Outputs: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

There are dedicated functions to solve this problem with a typical one-liner.

1. `std::sregex_token_iteraor`. This can iterate over tokens, defined by a `std::regex` in a `std::string`. Please see [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_token_iterator).
2. `std::distance`. This will take 2 iterators and counts the hops from the first iterator to the second iterator. Please see [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance).

With the available [constructors](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_token_iterator/regex_token_iterator), we set the iterator to the first element and the last element. The last element will be set with the empty default constructor (number 1) using the default initializer `{}`.

`std::distance` will then count the hops between the first found token and the last found token. And that is the number of overall found tokens. This is your result.

And with the above we get the following one-liner:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>
#include <iterator>

const std::string s{ "abcabcd abcde xab a b"};
const std::regex re{ "ab" };

int main() {
    std::cout << std::distance(std::sregex_token_iterator(s.begin(), s.end(), re), {});
}
```